# What is the best data structure to represent a conditional list of survey questions?

Tags: data-structures, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

In the current domain I'm working in, we can send surveys that have a list of questions. When designing the survey, you can create conditionals per question that determine which question it will ask next. Questions could have multiple conditionals. Some questions may not have any conditionals at all.

So an example might be:

If Q1 answer > 5, then go to Q3 else go to Q2.

Using IDs, I can make a list or map of Question objects work, but it's not great if I want to traverse from the beginning to figure out the path someone took through a Survey. So I'm wondering what recommendations people might have for another data structure to solve this problem.

So far I've thought about a tree or a directed acyclic graph (with conditional edges). I haven't found any good examples of using a tree to conditionally choose a path based on dynamic expressions.

Represented as tree:

```
     Q1
    / \
   Q2  Q3
  / \   |
Q4  Q5  Q5
|    |  |
Q6  Q7  Q7
```

Represented as DAG:

```
     Q1
     /\
   Q2  Q3
  / \  /
Q4   Q5  
|    | 
Q6   Q7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure will always depend on details of the problem domain.  If *every* rule is of the form you showed: `if f(Q_n) then Qi else Qj`, it's straightforward. Each question has an associated `if` of that form. Unless there are artificial limits on what Qi and Qj can be, the data structure you want is a DAG or directed acyclic graph. The acyclic part is because you probably never want to have a "loop" that takes a user back to a question they've already answered.

The nodes of the DAG will be the questions, and each will have 2, 1, or zero out-edges.

There are many ways to represent a DAG, but you probably want something simple.  A node will be a tuple

```
(question, condition, trueChild, falseChild)
```

The condition encoding is up to you.  Questions that have only one successor are no problem.  Just make the corresponding tuple

```
(question, TRUE, trueChild, null)
```

If you want to allow more complex rules, things can get much hairier, but the scheme above should be quite simple and fun to implement.

Making it robust will requires a check for cycles.

Tracking a user's history will be a traversal from the root guided by the answer sequence. Evaluate the condition at each node with the user's answer and take the respective branch.

It's probably simplest to just store the nodes in an array where maybe the index corresponds to (question number - 1). Then the child pointers can be indices.

So your example:

```
     Q1
     /\
   Q2  Q3
  / \  /
Q4   Q5  
|    | 
Q6   Q7
```

will look like (in C)

```c
typedef struct node {
  int number; // Not absolutely needed, but probably handy.
  CONDITION condition; // up to you
  int trueChild, falseChild;
} QUESTION;

typedef QUESTION SURVEY[MAX_SURVEY_LENGTH];

#define EMPTY (-1)
#define INDEX(Number) ((Number) - 1)

SURVEY survey = {
  { 1, {...}, INDEX(2), INDEX(3) },
  { 2, {...}, INDEX(4), INDEX(5) },
  { 3, True, INDEX(5), EMPTY },
  { 4, True, INDEX(6), EMPTY },
  { 5, True, INDEX(7), EMPTY },
  { 6, N_A, EMPTY, EMPTY },
  { 7, N_A, EMPTY, EMPTY },
}
```

Now suppose you have a string of responses that someone made. The algorithm for traversing the DAG to find the questions they saw would be:

```c
LIST *get_questions(int question_number, LIST *responses)
{
  LIST *result = create_empty_list();
  int nextIndex = INDEX(question_number);
  while (nextIndex != EMPTY && !is_empty(responses)) {
    QUESTION *q = survey + nextIndex;
    add(result, q);
    nextIndex = get_condition_value(&q->condition, first(responses))) 
        ? q->trueChild 
        : q->falseChild;
    responses = all_but_first(responses);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Gene. I did end up going with a DAG. It was a bit more complex because a question could have more than 2 branching paths (true/false).